# SQL Query to match unlinked data

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have three tables:

```
TABLE A

idA     variable
1       Number of hats
2       Number of scarves
3       Number of mittens


TABLE B

idB     name
1       Andy
2       Betty
3       Cedric
4       Daphne


TABLE C

idA     idB     value
1       1       15
1       2       2
1       3       89
2       1       10
2       3       3
2       4       1504
3       2       12
3       3       4
3       4       1
```

Looking at the table, it's relatively simple to work out - we know how many hats (2) and mittens (12) that she owns, but not how many scarves. Likewise, for Daphne we know how many scarves (1504) and mittens (1) she owns, but not the amount of hats.

However, I'd like a list of fields that there ISN'T information for - I would have a returned result looking something like this (if I asked for Andy)

```
idA     variable
3       Number of mittens
```

Any idea how I do that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query works:

```
SELECT B.name, A.variable
FROM B
CROSS JOIN A
LEFT JOIN C ON C.idA = A.idA AND C.idB = B.idB
WHERE C.value IS NULL
```

Its the `CROSS JOIN` that is key, it says `JOIN` every record in `B` to every record in `A`. Once you've done that you can easily check which combinations of `idA` and `idB` don't have a corresponding record in `C`.

[Tested on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7181f/9/0)

**Result:**

```
NAME       UNKNOWN VARIABLE
-------------------------------
Andy       Number of mittens
Betty      Number of scarves
Daphne     Number of hats
```

Comment: Before bothering to work this out myself I tested each of the other answers on the same SQLFiddle and none of them work...

Comment: Hats off to you, sir - that's exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins to associate 2 tables.

In your case, if you ask for Andy and you wanna know the number of mittens, you'll have:

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM B
INNER JOIN C on B.idB = C.idB
WHERE id.A = 3
```

Responding to your comment, you try something like that:

```
SELECT name, variable
FROM B
RIGHT JOIN C on B.idB = C.idB
RIGHT JOIN A on C.idA = A.idA
WHERE C.idA IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) but I don't want to know the number of mittens - I want to know that I *don't* know the number of mittens for Andy (or more accurately, a list of things I don't know about Andy)

Answer (score 1):

```
select idA, variable
from a
where idA not in (select idA from c where idB = 1)
```